# Gradle task launched in background goes into stopped state

Tags: bash, shell, gradle, jobs

I have a couple of bash scripts which perform a task using gradle wrapper and call `sbt run`.
If I launch them in background like
`bash -c ./1.sh & bash -c ./2.sh & bash -c ./3.sh & bash -c ./4.sh &`
then `1`, `2` and `3` go into stopped state while `4` outputs to the terminal and executes.
Bringing `1`, `2` or `3` to the foreground resumes their execution.

How do I execute all in background in started state?

Comment: Is option `-c` necessary?

Comment: No @pynexj, it does not.

Comment: Does not work with/without it @Cyrus

Answer (score 2):

This is a gradle specific issue. It seems that gradle tries to read from stdin and any background process that tries to read from controlling terminal is immediately [suspended](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Access-to-the-Terminal.html#Access-to-the-Terminal).

depending on shells, in bash I get the following output when try to run gradle build in the background:

```
$ gradle build &
[1] 32305
$
[1]+  Stopped                 gradle build
```

in zsh:

```
$ gradle build &
[1] 31173
$
[1]  + 31173 suspended (tty input)  gradle build
```

A workaround is to redirect /dev/null to stdin so the gradle process doesn't read from controlling terminal:

```
$ gradle build </dev/null & 
[2] 33139

> Configure project :
hello world

> Task :buildEnvironment

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project 'tmp'
------------------------------------------------------------

classpath
No dependencies

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

[2]    33139 done       gradle build < /dev/null
```

PS: my gradle.build file is simply:

```
println 'hello, world'
```